# How to view all projects in same window in IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea

How to view all projects in same window in IntelliJ

I have imported 3 projects from source control and Iwant to see all projects in same window. How i can do?
I tried module and view-->appearance options it didn't help for me.

I need to view like the attached screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just import the projects as modules

File -> New -> Module/Module From Existing Sources

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can have them in same directory and mark them as modules.

Comment: D:\workspace

HereI have imported 2 projects and they are in folders like,

automation-qa1
automation-qa2

Now what changes i need to do in intellij?

Comment: Just open workspace as a project and right click on workspace and New -> Module and provide path of automation-qa1 as content root